# How to provide a workflow in C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, workflow

I am building a project to automate the paper work in an organization. I have several tasks and i need to set a work flow for them using microsoft workflow item.
I am using visual studio 2010 and C#.
I am using microsoft SQL server for the database.
Any ideas on how to implement that? It would be great if an example exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328)

[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)

[Developing Applications with the Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489396.aspx)

[Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en)

Forum: [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wfprerelease/threads)

Answer (score 1):

have you looked into [windows workflow foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328)? it's specifically meant for these kinds of things. You can create a workflow with workflow items along the way to have a clearly structured path through your application. If you are looking to replace paperwork I image that it has to be done correctly every time. You even get a nice graphical editor in VS 2010

Comment: Oh the nightmares of a "nice graphical editor" ... at least SharePoint isn't part of the equation (yet).

Comment: true, i generally prefer working in code as well, especially with wpf because the auto-generated code can become really messy. the workflow editor is good (imo) for it's purpose. it's a bit easier to see the flow with a graphical editor than in code.